# How to replace the whitespace around certain characters?

Tags: regex

I am working on some free text for that I need to do some data cleaning, I have a question (out of many, which I will ask later I am sure):

I need to replace the following combinations:

`[ ; ]`  (space before and after the punctuation)

`[;]` (no space before and after the punctuation)

`[ ;]` (only space before the punctuation)

to

`[; ]` (only space after the punctuation)

...where the punctuation can be one of `[;:,.]`. How can I do this with a regex?

Comment: What’s the programming language or tool?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: It looks you're cleaning up sentence punctuation.  If that's true, shouldn't you match `!` (exclamation point) as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible expression would be:

```
\s?([;:,.])\s?
```

and depending on the programming language or tool you are using, you have to use `$1`, `\\1` or `\1` for the backreference and the replacement would be e.g. `$1` (there is a space after `1`).

**Explanation:**

```
\s?      - match at most one whitespace character
 (...)   - capture group, storing the matched characters in a reference
  [...]  - character class, matching one of the characters inside
```

**References:** [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

But again: The expression can differ, depending on the tool/language you are using. E.g. a similar expression for `sed` would look like:

```
/ *\([;:,.]\) */\1 /
```

but this would also trim the spaces around the punctuation (there is probably a better way, but I'm not so familiar with `sed`).

Comment: +1, but I think @Lucas is right; you should use `\s*`, not `\s?`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `\s*([;:,.])\s*` and replace with `'$1 '` (single quotes added to emphasise the space after the back-reference. It's a cross between Felix's first and last suggestion, so it could clean multiple spaces including tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what language you're using on *how* to move it into the cleaned form, `[; ]`, but you can match any of the punctuation marks by enclosing them in `[]`, like `[;:,.]`.

Once you have your pattern complete, you can replace the matches with your clean version. In at least Java, you could replace it with something like `"\[$<GroupNumber> \]"`, with the `<GroupNumber>` referring to the parenthesized group with your punctuation mark, like 1, 2, 3, etc., based on the order of the groups.

Remember, depending on the language you're using, you might need to escape backslashes. If you are using Java, then for all the examples above, you need to use `\\` in place of `\`.

Comment: In most (I assume all) flavors, the dot does not need to be escaped in a character class. Only `^` at the beginning and `-` everywhere but not at the beginning or the end are special in a character class.

Comment: Right you are! I wasn't thinking :-p Good catch

Comment: Java's flavor doesn't support named groups yet (they're being added in Java7/JDK1.7).  Also, I don't think the OP wants to match the square brackets; that he's just using them to make the whitespace visible to us.  Is that right, @lokhart?

Comment: @Alan Moore: Well, I'm not sure what you mean by named groups. If you mean the <GroupNumber>, I guess I should make it more clear I'm referring to a number like 1, 2, 3, etc. Hmm, I was wondering why everyone else didn't have brackets in their patterns :-p. I can always remove this answer if it doesn't add much more to any of the others.

Comment: @Zach: Never mind.  I saw the angle brackets and went into "named-group" mode without bothering to wonder why someone would name a group "GroupNumber".  Obviously it was past my bedtime. :-/